# Filter based on selected categories React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

```
  const recipes = [
    { name: 'Chicken-Curry-with-White-Rice', time: '35', tags: ['Indian'] },
    { name: 'Herby-Fish-Rolls', time: '35', tags: ['SeaFood'] },
    { name: 'Chicken-Shawarma-Tacos', time: '15', tags: ['Chicken', 'Quick & Easy'] },
    { name: 'Chicken-Zurbian', time: '55', tags: ['Chicken'] },
    { name: 'Shrimp-Scampi', time: '10', tags: ['SeaFood', 'Quick & Easy'] },
    { name: 'Baked-Fish-Fillet-in-Parchment-Paper', time: '40', tags: [ 'SeaFood'] },
    { name: 'Teriyaki-Chicken-with-Broccoli', time: '25', tags: ['Asian', 'Chicken'] },
    { name: 'Thai-Style-Chicken', time: '30', tags: ['Chicken'] },
    { name: 'Chicken-Shawarma-Salad', time: '10', tags: ['Chicken'] },
    { name: 'Bulgur-Salad-with-Grilled-Chicken', time: '25', tags: ['Chicken'] },
  ]

const recipesCategories = ['Asian', 'Indian', 'SeaFood', 'Quick & Easy', 'Chicken'];

    
const [filteredRecipes, setFilteredRecipes] = useState(recipes)

  {recipesCategories.map((recipe) => {
              return (
                <RecipeCategory recipeCategory={recipeCategory} filteredRecipes={filteredRecipes} setFilteredRecipes={setFilteredRecipes} />
              )
            })}



{filteredRecipes.map((recipe) => (
    <>
        <RecipeSlide recipe={recipe} />

    </>
)
)}
```

I have a list of categories(recipesCategories) each with their own button mapped using the RecipeCategory Component.
Each Recipe Component has a state to check if its selected or not. On render they are all selected. If the category is selected then add any recipe with the tag that matches the category to the filteredRecipes so it can be displayed.

The function below; lives inside the RecipeCategory Component, whenver someone clicks on a category and it's selected I want to update the filteredRecipes array to include those with tag equals the category.
const ChangeRecipeList = () => {

```
    let list = recipes;
    let newFilteredList = [];

    console.log('Recipe Catgory:', recipeCategory)

    newFilteredList = list.filter((Recipe) => selected && Recipe.tags.includes(recipeCategory) )
    console.log('State List:', filteredRecipes)

    console.log('Updated List:', newFilteredList)
    setFilteredRecipes(newFilteredList)
}
```

Comment: You haven't really stated what the problem is with the code you've written. Does it error? Does it produce the wrong set of data? Is the data not being rendered properly? If you could narrow down the scope of the problem by debugging your code that would help both you and us figure out a solution.

Comment: I'm not getting the desired behavior result unfortunately. Let me try and create a sandbox

Comment: [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/wizardly-panini-dsy7m6?file=%2Fpages%2Fcomponents%2FRecipeCategory.js&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A15%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A34%2C%22startColumn%22%3A15%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A34%7D%5D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having each category component maintain its own state:

1. Lift it up to the parent component
2. Switch the state to be an array of objects where each object has the interface `{ id, name, selected }`. When a category button is clicked the handler (that is passed down to the component) is called and toggles the `selected` property for the appropriate category. This involves a little more code but may be a little easier to visualise/manage.

In this example using your data I'm passing in both the recipes and categories as `config`. I'm creating the categories state on-the-fly, and then calling `filterRecipes` in the recipe section to filter only those recipes where the categories state includes some of the tags.

Note: testing this "Teriyaki-Chicken-with-Broccoli" appears when both "Asian" and "Seafood" are selected. Hopefully that's an expectation.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example({ config }) {

  // `map` over the categories and create an array
  // of category objects with their own "selected" value
  const [
    categories,
    setCategories
  ] = useState(config.categories.map((name, id) => {
    return { id, name, selected: true };
  }));
  
  // When a category button is clicked we
  // extract its value, and then `map` over the state
  // toggling the selected value if the category name
  // matches the button value 
  function handleCategory(e) {
    const { value } = e.target;
    const updated = categories.map(c => {
      if (c.name === value) c.selected = !c.selected;
      return c;
    });
    setCategories(updated);
  }
  
  // First we get an array of category names that
  // are selected, and then we `filter` the recipes
  // where some of the tags are included in the selected
  // categories array
  function filterRecipes() {

    const selectedCategories = categories.filter(c => {
      return c.selected;
    }).map(c => c.name);

    return recipes.filter(r => {
      return r.tags.some(tag => {
        return selectedCategories.includes(tag);
      });
    });

  }
  
  // Two main sections - the categories,
  // and the recipes. A handler is passed to each category
  // component which updates the state, and for the recipes
  // we `map` over the result of calling `filterRecipes`.
  return (
    <main>
      
      <section className="categories">
        {categories.map(category => {
          return (
            <Category
              key={category.id}
              data={category}
              handleCategory={handleCategory}
            />
          );
        })}
      </section>
      
      <ul className="recipes">
        {filterRecipes().map(recipe => {
          return (
            <Recipe
              key={recipe.name}
              data={recipe}
            />
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    
    </main>
  );

}

function Category({ data, handleCategory }) {
  
  // Create a class string for the component
  const cn = [
    'category',
    data.selected && 'active'
  ].join(' ');
  
  return (
    <button
      className={cn}
      type="button"
      value={data.name}
      onClick={handleCategory}
    >{data.name}
    </button>
  );

}

function Recipe({ data }) {
  return (
    <li>{data.name}</li>
  );
}

const recipes=[{name:"Chicken-Curry-with-White-Rice",time:"35",tags:["Indian"]},{name:"Herby-Fish-Rolls",time:"35",tags:["SeaFood"]},{name:"Chicken-Shawarma-Tacos",time:"15",tags:["Chicken","Quick & Easy"]},{name:"Chicken-Zurbian",time:"55",tags:["Chicken"]},{name:"Shrimp-Scampi",time:"10",tags:["SeaFood","Quick & Easy"]},{name:"Baked-Fish-Fillet-in-Parchment-Paper",time:"40",tags:["SeaFood"]},{name:"Teriyaki-Chicken-with-Broccoli",time:"25",tags:["Asian","Chicken"]},{name:"Thai-Style-Chicken",time:"30",tags:["Chicken"]},{name:"Chicken-Shawarma-Salad",time:"10",tags:["Chicken"]},{name:"Bulgur-Salad-with-Grilled-Chicken",time:"25",tags:["Chicken"]}];

const categories=["Asian","Indian","SeaFood","Quick & Easy","Chicken"];

const node = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(node);
root.render(<Example config={{ recipes, categories}} />);
```

```css
.category { padding: 0.25rem 0.4rem; }
.active { background-color: lightgreen; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: BRUV.. You manhandled JavaScript. Thanks alot

Comment: That may be the finest compliment I've received on here :) @Ibra